# My PHP program won't store my ticker information and it gives me several warnings

Tags: php

I am running a PHP program to store information from a website through their API ticker, and for that I've made two files; "db.JSON" and "index.php". The database file is empty with only two brackets "[]" and my index files code looks like this:

```php
while (true) {
    $dataSource = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.mywebsite.dk/api/ticker/"), true);
    print_r($dataSource);
    $db = json_decode(file_get_contents("db.json"), true);
    array_push($db, $dataSource);
    file_put_contents("db.json", json_encode($db));
    sleep(6);
}
```

But when I run `php '/home/emil/Dropbox/ElementaryOS/Bit2/index.php'`  I get this error:

```
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1455739785
    [result]    => 43
)
PHP Warning: file_get_contents(db.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/emil/Dropbox/ElementaryOS/Bit2/index.php on line 5

PHP Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/emil/Dropbox/ElementaryOS/Bit2/index.php on line 6
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1455739796
    [result] => 44
)

PHP Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/emil/Dropbox/ElementaryOS/Bit2/index.php on line 6
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1455739806
    [result] => 44
)
```

And so on, you get the idea.

The `db.json` file is in the folder with my index file. Therefore I have been looking for some answers different places on the internet to solve the problem, including this forum and the things I found did not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: PHP can't find your `db.json` file - try putting in a full path, making sure the permissions are right, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to be more careful in defining $db. What if the file doesn't exist yet, or if the data is empty or corrupt? I'd add some validation and check if the file_exists().

```
<?php
   while(true) {
   $dataSource = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.mywebsite.dk/api/ticker/"), true);
   print_r($dataSource);
   if (file_exists("db.json")) {
       $db = json_decode(file_get_contents("db.json"), true);
   } else {
       $db = array();
   }
   if (!is_array($db) || empty($db)) {
       $db = array();
   }
   array_push($db, $dataSource);
   file_put_contents("db.json", json_encode($db));
   sleep(6);
}
?>
```

Also, make sure the file is writable and the directory you are writing to is writable by PHP (Apache/Server). You also may need to use a full paths to the files you are working with.

Comment: Oops... It should be if (file_exists("db.json")) { ... }  I forgot the closing )